# odd-even merging for two sorted lists of arbitrary sizes

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have the following scenario: I am given two (previously) sorted sequences of numbers and I need to merge them using a merging network (such as batcher's http://bit.ly/ytbmqE). However, these networks are designed to work for sequences of 2^k size, which is not my case.

Can anyone suggest a way to do that? Ideally one that doesn't involve forcing the list to be of some size that is a multiple of 2 (such as by appending zeroes to the beginning for instance).

Comment: Why you don't like append something to your list? it's not time consuming job.

Comment: I'm dealing with extremely large sequences and I have limited memory. So... say N (my total number of items) is not a power of 2 (assume it is 2^(t)-1 to account for the worst case scenario), I will have to add 2^t+1 elements to my list, which is potentially a very large number.

Comment: if it is 2^(t)-1 you should add one number, but in all you should add at most two time number (Also you can do not add it and treat with out of range numbers as very big number) So make it two time slower in initialization is not bad.

Answer (score 3):

Your input array is of size x and if it's not in the format of 2<sup>t</sup> it will be as: 2<sup>t</sup>< x<2<sup>t+1</sup>, so you can add 2<sup>t+1</sup> - x elements with **max value** to your input (makes it as most twice) and then apply one of a common network for sorting. and finally remove last 2<sup>t+1</sup> - x elements from your result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two choices but i could be wrong:

1. Fill with -99999 or 99999 and in your end result ignore the tail of 99999's.
2. Fill with nulls, and in each comparison allow null to lose in a try catch exception statement. Depending on your language you may still need to strip the tail of nulls from your data structure.

EDIT:

There is a way to do it without using fill values, but it requires multiple merging. E.g. merge a subset of the two lists, then take some of these numbers and mix them with the numbers you left out the first time, and then merge two lists again, then merge the top halfs and the bottom halfs .. type thing.. kinda messy.

Comment: Thanks! That's quite similar to what the previous person proposed. But as I mentioned in a comment above, the reason why I'm avoiding adding new elements is because I may (potentially) have to add a very large number of items and I don't have the memory for that.

Comment: You will only run out of memory if you are currently using over half your memory which seems unlikely.. I suppose I have another answer for you which I will post soon.

Comment: Thanks for putting some thought into it. The setting in which I'm working is actually a bit more complicated to explain but the simplified version of it is "I must avoid adding new items" :) 
After reading some more, I'm almost convinced that it is not possible to merge these 2 lists (using odd-even merge) if the sum of their number of elements is not a power of 2.

Comment: Ah it's tough sorry mate. I don't have a solution for you.

Comment: No worries! I'll keep working on it and if I eventually come up with something I'll post here.

Answer (score 1):

Take the network for the least power of two greater than the input size and delete all of the comparators that involve non-existent elements.

Answer (score 0):

This page is quite old, but I lately had to find a solution for this problem, with the requirement of not having any memory overhead. The intuition is the same as the Edit in Rusty Rob answer.
If you just want the code, you can find a Rust implementation on [my github](https://github.com/A-GX/Generalised_Odd-Even-Merge)

In the following, I give the pseudocode algorithm, a more in-depth intuition on how it works and then a somewhat rigorous proof of correctness, basing myself on the initial paper by Batcher [Batcher, K.E.: Sorting networks and their applications. AFIPS ’68] :

[image]

Intuitively, the only difference with the obvious case (i.e. when the list has 2n elements), is that stepping in between sublist does not scale the same way as stepping in between inner elements of the sublist. We thus need to keep track of how where and when to jump. Note that the protocol given above allows to merge two lists of fully arbitrary lengths (proof below), which trivially implies that we can use it to sort any list through the second protocol.

If you want a more technical view on how it works (while being less tedious than the proof below), refer to the comment in my code, on github.

To make it easier for me, as I need some formula, I post the proof as screen of my LateX document. The following should be proving the merging algorithm presented above is correct:

[image]
[image]